# Create Web Deployment zip file from TFS build

Tags: web, deployment, tfs, msbuild

Using TFS 2010 and I have a build project consisting of 2 solutions. One is a MVC solution with web pages the other is a solution containing multiple projects. These are various WFC services. I have added the criteria to publish each project in both solutions.
If I build either of them from VS - I get the zip files created.
If I use msbuild from a command prompt and build the WFC solution - I get the zip files.
Same for the MVC.
I then have a build project that builds both solutions, and I have as parameters 
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package

When I submit that build - it completes. But in the "_PublishedWebsites" folder I only get a package for the MVC project.

I've tried a LOT of variations but can't get the WFC solution to create the packages for the projects. I even named the pubxml files the same in each WFC project and tried passing that in as another parameter but the same results - MVC is correct; nothing for the WFC.
Even tried changes to Debug|AnyCPU versus Debug|Any CPU (space added).

I am thinking I have some little thing off that is biting me - but I can't find it.
Appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

The WCF projects need to have been created as Web Applications and not just Websites. The default behavior you want is only available in Web Application.

There is walkthough on how to do the conversion on MSDN ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)). I tend to modify the documentation to be an in place upgrade by creating a blank web application and copying the project file over the top of the existing location.

You can then open that new project in VS (giving you two views of the same thing) and then adding the hidden files. Once working you can then delete the WebSite project and you will be left with thebWeb Application that will output to _PublishedWebsites.